# How would I handle an Admin on a node.js blog?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, admin, production-environment

I'm a beginner in back-end development using express and mongoose.

I'm creating a blog that will only have one admin that can edit, create, delete posts. How would I handle the admin? Does it make sense to create a mongoose model just for the admin or can I have his password and username in a .env file and just make a comparison in the login route?

Is the .env file safe during production? Can a client access process.env through his browser?

Are jsonwebtokens enough for authentication or should I use passport.js?

Answer (score 1):

Implementing admin is pretty simple; if you already have a schema for regular users, just add a field that specifies whether they are admin or not:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        ...
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        ...
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'user',
        enum: ['admin', 'user']
    }
})
```

Then, for all the protected routes that only admin can do (like editing, creating, etc) place a middleware function before it to check the role field on the user.

```
    const restricted = (req, res, next) => { 
        if (user.role !== 'admin') { // assuming you pass user info
            return res.status(403).json({
                status: 'fail',
                message: 'Unauthorized to access this route'
            })
        }
        next()
    }
```

Comment: then every one can become `admin` by filling `{ role : admin }`..

Answer (score 0):

If your blog is only used by you, you can certainly use an `env` file to store your account and password.

However, if you are going to make a "normal" application, you should create a user table in your database and use an authentication mechanism to keep your data safe.

In addition, `jwt` is usually used to authenticate the RESTful interface, but there are also many other authentication methods, such as `sessionid` and `oauth`, you should choose the right authentication method according to your needs.

Comment: The blog will only be used by one user. So it is perfectly fine/secure to have sensitive information in a .env file while the site in running in production mode? Is that how it is usually done for 1-user websites?

Comment: If your server is set up with the correct inbound/outbound policy, ssh security policy, and the env file is not exposed to public (e.g. static file service by nginx), then it is safe in most cases. While this is not the best practice, but sufficient for a single user system.

Comment: Essentially, a database is just some files with additional authentication. The premise of security is that "your server is secure", without this premise, it makes no difference how your user information is stored.